# Point-in-Polygon Analysis Using Python GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

There is a date frame containing:

```
0   1   POLYGON ((37.787073 55.74702199999999, 37.7843...   1   POINT (37.34519 55.73756)
1   1   POLYGON ((37.787073 55.74702199999999, 37.7843...   2   POINT (37.23459 56.23456)
2   1   POLYGON ((37.787073 55.74702199999999, 37.7843...   3   POINT (36.29575 55.23458)
3   2   POLYGON ((37.458311 55.803885, 37.464054 55.80...   1   POINT (37.34519 55.73756)
4   2   POLYGON ((37.458311 55.803885, 37.464054 55.80...   2   POINT (37.23459 56.23456)
5   2   POLYGON ((37.458311 55.803885, 37.464054 55.80...   3   POINT (36.29575 55.23458)
```

At the same time, the geopandas does not allow defining 2 columns with the geometry type. Point is a geometry datatype, but polygon is not.

```
Int64Index: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------        --------------  -----   
 0   place_id      6 non-null      int64   
 1   polygon_zone  6 non-null      object  
 2   user_id       6 non-null      int64   
 3   geometry      6 non-null      geometry
dtypes: geometry(1), int64(2), object(1)
```

I wanted to check the occurrence of a point like this:

`result['result'] = result['geometry'].within(Polygon(result['polygon_zone']))`

However, this method does not work, tell me how to solve this problem.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

hard to say how you ended up with the GDF w/ 2 geometry cols, but you probably want to use `sjoin`, this will return a GDF that you can then extract what you need from.

```
gpd.sjoin(PolyDF, PointDF)
```

if you need to deconstruct the single GDF that you have... *not sure what specific cols have to come along*

```
PolygonDF = result[["place_id", "polygon_zone"]]
PolygonDF.columns = ["place_id", "geometry"]
PointDF = result[["user_id", "geometry"]]
```

if you could add how you came up with the initial GeoDataFrame it would help